# How to set linux application as "global" avaliable in OS?

Tags: c, linux, centos

I have C application running under CentOS

I need set is as global. I write a function to "set global". It is working but i need another solution for it.

Compiler is `gcc`

```
void set_global(void) {
    /*Function to set program_name as global application.*/
    puts(ANSI_COLOR_RED"WARINING! ROOT PERMISSION OR ADMINISTRATOR NEED!"ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
    puts("Set "ANSI_COLOR_GREEN"program_name "ANSI_COLOR_RESET" as global application.");
    system("sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/program_name ");
    system("sudo cp -r program_name /usr/bin");
    system("export PATH=\"/usr/bin:$PATH\"");
    system("sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/program_name ");
    system("sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/geo.txt");
    system("sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/points.txt");
    system("sudo cp -r geo.txt /usr/bin");
    system("sudo cp -r points.txt /usr/bin");
    system("sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/geo.txt");
    system("sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/points.txt");
}
```

Before running application I must paste:
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in terminal.

It works, but I think I'm doing it wrong.
Copy application to `/usr/bin` it is good solution?

Answer (score 1):

System directories such as `/usr` and `/lib` are normally managed by the system package manager, so that modifying the contents of these directories manually may interfere with the system package manager operations. This is why it is not a good practice. People normally install 3rd-party software into [`/usr/local`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html) or [`/opt`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s13.html), see [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html) for more details.

To make the application "global" add the path to the directory with its executable into `PATH` environment variable. You can do that by adding the following line into user's `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` (or whatever startup file your shell uses):

```
export PATH="<dir>":"$PATH"
```

`~/.bash_profile` is evaluated on login, `~/.bashrc` on opening a new terminal (see [The Bash Shell Startup Files](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html) for more details). Alternatively, you can manually do `source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.bashrc` to make that setting come into effect into your current shell.

To avoid having to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<dir>` link your application with `-L<dir> -Wl,-rpath=<dir>`. Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` may break other applications, see [LD_LIBRARY_PATH considered harmful](https://gms.tf/ld_library_path-considered-harmful.html).